# Using Vue3 Composition API with script setup and typescript - is there a way to use complex nested defaults?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am using Vue3 Composition API with script setup and typescript for my project. In the docs we are provided [this example](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#props-default-values):

```js
export interface Props {
  msg?: string
  labels?: string[]
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  msg: 'hello',
  labels: () => ['one', 'two']
})
```

Is there a way to use an interface as a property in the defaults?

I'm very new to typescript so I'm not sure I'm asking the right question. I want to do something like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

export interface WindowConfig {
    showTitlebar: boolean
}

export interface WindowType {
    title: string,
    config?: WindowConfig 
}

const DEFAULTS = {
    title: 'Default title',
    config: { showTitlebar: true } as WindowConfig
} as WindowType

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<WindowType>(), DEFAULTS)

</script>
```

However I am met with an error saying that `DEFAULTS` doesn't match the requirements for withDefaults.

```
Argument of type 'WindowType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InferDefaults<WindowType>'.
  Types of property 'config' are incompatible.ts(2345)
```

Why is this happening and is there any documentation that can lead me in the right direction to fix it?

[Here is an interactive example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9U01vozAQ/SsjX5JIUXLoDaWtum1W6mq1W21Z9cLFwBCcgseyTUkV5b93DCQ0VRWEkJmPN+/NjPfizpjFW4MiEiuXWWU8OPSNgUrqzXUivEvETaITjTtD1oPSHm0hM4QXpXNq70kXagP7RAM/rqQ2Vr7CVNoIUqIKJeceLgDE7waP6T6kRuC8VXoz721ZV+A2Oq83YLLTeXhY/7z7/zt+husvQJMHLGRT+f5/coYYwf4LXW8bhANId1aKK42mQDbUXS4hLpUDfjUxfGmpZcogoZVWhxNZQGv562jkVzfMNkUO+wxXNDrzijSjjeYppVvM/FF2MM1gz6LPgo7Is4HUS/kOOUGLsEEPUg8cSrR4C49+4pgqgpM1Qo8fpMmU3phG30tjyThuZKt8OXTPTXMslMan4FqN1W+ms/lJW8dgtexXiBdGzHl1+k4vto4071c3m0RkVBtVof1rgmheL55EP5hEyKqi9ldnC9MYBsY5JWav39i3bhdsiXiy6NCyDHHyeWm5Cb17/fwHd3w+OWvKm4qjLzj/oaOqCRz7sB+Nzpn2p7iO7WMd1ppHHrv1zqN2R1GBaIg8dPGJ4Et2f0H6SPdqcdXl8eaJwweZDD6F). In this example you can see I have made a function that requires the type `WindowConfig` This tells me the issue lies with Vue not Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the necessary dependencies and functions implemented, this code should be able to run without any issues.
But if you have any error, I can know the reason by checking your all code.

Comment: I have added more context with an error message and an interactive example.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering that error because the `config` property in the `Props` interface expects a value of type `Config`, but in your code, you are assigning an object literal directly to it.

You can get rid from this error by defining a object literal in your config property along with the Config type.

```
export interface Props {
  title: string
  config?: Config | { showTitlebar: boolean }
}
```

Or you can also explicitly cast the object literal to `Config` type.

```
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), (props: Props) => ({
    title: props.title || 'Default Title',
    config: {
        showTitlebar: props.config?.showTitlebar ?? true
    } as WindowConfig
}))
```

Comment: https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UsFOAjEQ/ZVJL0hC8MBtAxhFDnpQoiReeinLLBS7bdPOsmvI/rvdLguihp6aee/NezPtgd1bO9wXyBI29qmTlsAjFRaU0JsJZ+Q5m3LNtcytcQQHcChSknuEGjJncugFda9hYBUZUhO6TKQIH1KvTTkzOpMbOHAN4fitKZeSFK6ES2BljEIRtPWVBssvi52cGmkCnpzUm0FbS6PBXXLpd+wZQE9gnbEeJlBK2j5iJgpF/maNmdS4aKDx2Wl60x/8cusdJRCD9y5sk477dzhyBbZYDcJfpAvh+lyPb9uNh/2yQdh023G480aH54h9OUtNbqVC92pJhlk4OzlyJpQy5XOsNWbHYEGzxfTzn/rOV02Ns4VDj26PnJ0wEm6D1MLz9xeswv0E5mZdqMC+Ar6hN6poMra0h0KvQ+wfvJj2KX6j8HhLP68Ite+G6rZVRz5n4VfNrox+jjsajqIu7JTV3+sY86I=

This solution still provides errors

Comment: @DanielTate The issue here is related to the usage of the `withDefaults` function. The `withDefaults` function expects a type with a signature of `(props: WindowType) => WindowConfig` to be provided as the second argument. I updated the answer.

Comment: Jindal Did you try this in the vue environment? It doesn't seem to work as expected. I get different errors, maybe this isn't possible?

Comment: I added another link at the bottom of my question that shows more details.